# Non Inverting op-amp grounding

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, grounding

I have this LM358 op amp as a non inverting amplifier used for high side current control.

I feed this ic with 5v on pin 8 and ground is pin 4.
Pin 2 and 3 are the inverting and non inverting inputs. I use a pot to change the gain of the op-amp in order to change the current output for the load when it's connected.

I've been searching about what's the best way to ground op-amps used as current controllers in situation like this but I can't found something convincing to me.

What I don't want is to introduce large current peaks on the ic when a load is connected on the output, that's why I use a 0.3mm trace on pin 4 that connects to sense resistor ground. Also I put a ground via near pin 4 in order to connect common ground of the pcb too.

[image: current_control]
[image: current control sch]

I don't know if this ground connection (trace from pin 4 of the op-amp to ground sense resistor) it's ok from what I want or I have to make some improvements.

Comment: What driver frequency response do you expect to load spectrum?  What is your error budget?

Comment: Where's your schematic?

Comment: I recently add the current control schematics

Comment: That's not a logical diagram = not a good schematic. Where are your answers?

Comment: Tony do you refer to the open loop frecuency response? Based on the doc on page 7 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358-n.pdf?&ts=1588875554212 this op amp has a 10mv offset voltage, with that for me its ok besides I know is not so precise on this kinds of measures.